# How can the lpClassName parameter of CreateWindowEx be optional

Tags: windows, winapi

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680.aspx), the `lpClassName` parameter of `CreateWindowEx` is optional.

> lpClassName [in, optional]

However, the documentation makes no mention of what it means to pass `NULL`. What's more, if `NULL` is passed, then there is no way for the window manager to find a window procedure for the new window.

So, is the documentation wrong? Or is it correct and there is some scenario where `NULL` is a valid value for `lpClassName`?

Comment: Bets open: I stand for "documentation wrong"

Comment: `CreateWindowEx` returns `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` in the casual case where `lpClassName` is `NULL`. But I'm not sure it's a documentation error, as the parameter is also marked as optional in the header files.

Comment: It is optional because it might not be a valid string.  It might be an ATOM.  I guess the type annotations aren't sophisticated enough to express dodgy type hacks.

Comment: @arx Could you flesh that out in an answer please.

Comment: @arx but passing an atom is not exactly passing NULL

Comment: @manuell I know.  I'm guessing this is the best they could do with what they'd got.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `lpClassName` parameter to `CreateWindowEx` is declared to be an `LPCTSTR` but it can actually be either a pointer to a string or a class atom returned by `RegisterClass` or `RegisterClassEx`.

Ideally the type annotation would specify precisely what's allowed for this parameter, but I guess the annotation language doesn't have a way of describing the types of things that don't match their declared type.

The best they could do is declare it as optional to indicate that the string might not be valid.

Comment: I accepted this, but I have to say I'm not convinced that it isn't just a documentation/annotation bug. In any case, given the type of question that I asked, I think this is the best answer that can be given. So thank you.