# Handle to window - undefined value

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm getting a handle to a window like this:

```
HWND Handle = CreateWindowEx(0, NULL, NULL,
                             WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                             CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                             300, 200, 0, 0,
                             NULL, 0);
```

Then I use it as an input parameter to a function which should gave the result to the window from that handle. But the function gave me error code which means "Bad argument".

When I debug the program and look at the value of `Handle`, it shows me that it has an "undefined value". Does anyone know what is the problem with this code?

Comment: No class name? No window name?

Comment: Marius hands are faster than me. You have invalid class name.

Comment: I use it normally in class, i wanted to ask short so i gave only this part. What do you mean about window name? MSDNA doc says that class name and window name are optional.

Comment: Its time for working example. Also for class name read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20615438/how-can-the-lpclassname-parameter-of-createwindowex-be-optional

Comment: undefined value? It should be `NULL` because of `lpClassName == NULL`, shouldn't it? Have you debugged with Debug mode, not Release mode?